# $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}{f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h \over h^2} $

Tags: limits

$f$ is twice-differentiable function at the domain of $\Bbb R$

\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0}{f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h \over h^2} 
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\left[{f(x+h)-f(x) \over h^2} -{f'(x)h \over h^2}\right] \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}{f(x+h)-f(x) \over h}{1\over h} -\lim_{h \to 0}{f'(x) \over h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}{f'(x)\over h} -\lim_{h \to 0}{f'(x) \over h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\left[{f'(x)\over h}-{f'(x)\over h}\right] \\
& = 0
\end{align}

Is the above reasoning correct? I especially concerns my repeating distribution of limits back and forth.

Comment: Are there any conditions on $f(x)$?

Comment: @thedilated yes. edited op

Comment: Writing $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}{f'(x)\over h} -\lim\limits_{h \to 0}{f'(x) \over h}$ isn't correct (it's undefined) since both limits are $\pm\infty$

Comment: Try writing out that quotient -- the thing inside the limit -- for $f(x) = 3x^2$, just to see what you get. Sometimes a concrete example can help you make a wise guess about a more general problem like this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You made an error at this step:

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0}{f(x+h)-f(x) \over h}{1\over h}=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}{f'(x) \over h} $

Because by doing so you assume that $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}{f(x+h)-f(x) \over h}$ and $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}{1 \over h}$ both exists which is clearly false for the latter.

Now since $f(x)$ is twice differentiable, then $f$ and $f'$ are continuous. Substituting $h=0$ into $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}{f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h \over h^2}$ gives us ${0 \over 0}$. 
(Note that we can directly let $h=0$ due to continuity!)

Now applying L'Hopital's rule by taking derivatives on the numerator and denominator **with respect to $h$** yields: $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}{f'(x+h)-f'(x) \over 2h}$.

Then it is clear that this expression is equivalent to ${1 \over 2} f''(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

By the Taylor formula
$$f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + \frac{1}{2}f''(x) h^2 + o(h^2)$$
Now substitute and get
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h^2} (f(x+h) -f(x) - f'(x)h) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h^2} (\frac{1}{2}f''(x) h^2 + o(h^2)) = \frac{1}{2}f''(x)$$

Answer (score 3):

The first and main error is in
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\left[{f(x+h)-f(x) \over h^2} -{f'(x)h \over h^2}\right]
= \lim_{h \to 0}{f(x+h)-f(x) \over h}{1\over h} -\lim_{h \to 0}{f'(x) \over h}
$$
because neither limit in the right-hand side exists (unless you're in a very very special situation, which is not assumed in the hypotheses).

The second mistake is in
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}{f(x+h)-f(x) \over h}{1\over h}= 
\lim_{h \to 0}{f'(x)\over h}
$$
When computing a limit, you cannot just take one part and substitute it with its limit; this is essentially the same as doing
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{0}{h}
$$

Comment: Last example is simple yet powerful. +1

Comment: Quick and flag the moderator

Comment: I got nine minute left 9 see you later